# Preparing Rails JSON for Ember Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

Ember-data seems to want an array of data for a hypothetical Color model to look like:

```
{
  "colors": [{
    name: "red"
  }, {
    name: "blue"
  }, {
    name: "green"
  }]
}
```

i.e. It wants a root element that is the plural of whatever type your model is.  I am wondering how to get rails to send JSON that way using the active_model_serializers gem.  Here is what I have:

```
# GET /colors
# GET /colors.json
def index
  @colors = Color.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @colors, :root => 'colors' }
  end
end
```

but this produces:

```
{
  colors: [
    {
      colors: {
        name: "red"
      }
    }, {
      colors: {
        name: "blue"
      }
    }, {
      colors: {
        name: "green"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

i.e.  There is a root element on the array *and* each object.  I want it just on the array.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a rails guy, but I know there is an Ember Data adapter/serializer ( `ActiveModelAdapter`/`ActiveModelSerializer`) which are meant specifically for rails backend api.  Are you using them?

Comment: And I'm sure you've looked through this page, https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by adding my own custom serializer

app/serializers/color_serializer.rb

```
class ColorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
  self.root = false
end
```

and then used

```
render json: @colors, each_serializer: ColorSerializer
```

which disabled the per-object root element while preserving the root element on the array.